# Flot Chart panning not working on mobile devices

Tags: cordova, flot

Im trying to make some stacked bar charts using the flot charts library on Cordova. The graphs work perfectly fine when I run them on google chrome but they do not pan on mobile devices. I tried it on an actual Android Lollipop device and an iPhone 6 simulator. Is there any solution? If not are there better chart libraries that support graph panning on mobile devices?